# Production: main@HEAD failed Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, netlify

Facing below error while build and deploy in netlify from github using `CI= npm run build`
Steps Followed :

1. npm run build in my local repo
2. pushed build folder to remote
3. automatically trigger deployment in netfily.

```
11:11:15 AM: make: Leaving directory '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-sass/build'
11:11:15 AM: gyp ERR! build error
11:11:15 AM: gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
11:11:15 AM: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
11:11:15 AM: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
11:11:15 AM: gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
11:11:15 AM: gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.167+
11:11:15 AM: gyp ERR! command "/opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v16.8.0/bin/node" "/opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
11:11:15 AM: gyp ERR! cwd /opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-sass
11:11:15 AM: gyp ERR! node -v v16.8.0
11:11:15 AM: gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
11:11:15 AM: gyp ERR! not ok
11:11:15 AM: Build failed with error code: 1
11:11:16 AM: Error during Yarn install
11:11:16 AM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
11:11:16 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
11:11:16 AM: Finished processing build request in 3m21.027438345s
```

Installed node-sass dependency any issue over here ?

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "demo-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```